# How to use jQuery $(this) to change the HTML of the element that used the "onclick" event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new at jQuery and I am a bit stuck with the use of $(this). Here is a simple example code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script>
            function change()
            {
                $(this).html("STOP");
            }
        </script>
    </head>


    <body>
        <h2 onclick="change()">GO</h2>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here, if I click the text "GO", then I expect it to change itself to "STOP". But it's not working. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to pass `this` to your function which refer to the `h2` element:

```
<h2 onclick="change(this)">GO</h2>
```

then you can pass that argument to your function:

```
function change(el) {
    $(el).html("STOP");
}
```

or better, you can use `.click()` event handler:

```
$('h2').click(function() {
    $(this).html("STOP");
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot (and also to others who answered)! Yeah I like the `click()` solution as well. But sometimes I need to generate the HTML elements using PHP and pass some unique arguments, and that's why I need to use inline JS. It's handy to know both solutions though :D

Answer (score 2):

The best approach:

```
<h2>GO</h2>
```

with

```
$('h2').click(function() {
    $(this).html("STOP");
});
```

Or if you still want to use inline handler (which you probably don't have to do if you use jQuery):

```
<h2 onclick="change(this)">GO</h2>
```

and

```
function change(obj) {
    $(obj).html("STOP");
}
```

The first approach is preferred because it allows you to be less dependent on HTML. If you change HTML structure you don't have to carry around those inline handlers. For this matter even more efficient approach would be to use CSS selector to target this element:

```
<h2 class="btn-go">GO</h2>
```

and then

```
$('.btn-go').click(function() {
    $(this).html("STOP");
});
```

Now javascript code doesn't even care about whether you use H2 or BUTTON tag, it just has to provide class `btn-go`.

Answer (score 2):

Use :

```
 <script>
    $('h2').click(function(){
      $(this).html('STOP')
    }
 </script>
```

And remove the onclick from your HTML.

```
<h2>GO</h2>
```

As a general rule, you shouldn't add inline Javascript code to your HTML, to keep display and functionality separate.

Answer (score 0):

As you have tagged jquery i would suggest you to Try below code using dynamic .on as its quite modern approach and its working in fiddle :-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("h2").on('click', function() {
    $(this).html("STOP");

});

});
```

and for your case try :-

```
 function change(e)
            {
                $(e).html("STOP");
            }
```

and in html :-

```
<h2 onclick="change(this)">GO</h2>
```

**Demo** :-

http://jsfiddle.net/DXQ5j/33/

Answer (score 0):

Here JSFIddle for this -- http://jsfiddle.net/Arindamnayak/r53t3f6d/

```
$("h2").click(function() {
                $(this).html("STOP");
            });

  <h2 >GO</h2>
```

Comment: Updated, it was not required, i misplaced the text, while copying.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `on`? It is dynamic and better than `click`.

```
$(selector).on("click",function () {
    //Your Code to Execute
});
```

Documentation: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Yeah, I too prefer that way. It works on embedded elements as well. That's cool. `click` is old-fashioned. Thumbs up!

Comment: this isn't dynamic. It's the same as `click`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery :

**Html :**

```
<h2>GO</h2>
```

**Script :**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('h2').click(function() {                
        $(this).html("STOP");
    });
});
```

[**jsfiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/bth1c35m/)

or you can use javascript :

```
<h2 onclick="changeme(this)">GO</h2>
<script>
    function changeme(element) {
    $(element).html("STOP");
}
</script>
```

[**jsfiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/bth1c35m/1/)

Answer (score -2):

onclick="onchange(this)

```
function change(obj)
            {
                $(obj).html("STOP");
            }
```

Comment: What does this answer add other than the information in existing answers..?